# dataGridView not showing data after DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I am new to C# and have simple method to show data from a table DimCustomer. I am calling this method from a button but its not displaying data. Although when i debug my code i can see data, but not displaying it. Any suggestions please

```
private void ShowGridData()
        {
            // create a connection object
            string ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
            "database=AdventureWorksDW2012;" + "server=DESKTOP-L9L3SMT\\SQL2K12;";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            // open the connection
            conn.Open();

            // Create a DataTableMapping object
            DataTableMapping myMapping = new DataTableMapping("DimCustomer", "mapCustomer");
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM DimCustomer where LastName='yang' and BirthDate='1966-04-08'", conn);

            // Call DataAdapter's TableMappings.Add method
            adapter.TableMappings.Add(myMapping);

            // Create a DataSet object and Call DataAdapter's Fill method
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "DimCustomer");
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 0;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
        }
```

Comment: It has been awhile since I have done WinForms, but does `dataGridView1.Invalidate()` solve the problem?

Comment: `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds;`this should be enogh  to have it working

Comment: If you don't create the columns for the dataGridView, there won't be any place to put the data

Comment: It seems pretty clear you need to do much more research on all those DB Provider objects.  You dont need table mapping, you dont need a local DataAdapter or the ViewManager and you dont really need a Dataset.  You do need to close and dispose of your connection and store dates as dates.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this instead?

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```